react native xcode , Flipper erros
I have these problem when trying to run my app using xcode. it's always a problem about Flipper , I try a lot of solutions nothing work.
the project info:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.68.5


For me i just added this line #include<Functional> on FlipperTransport file,  here is the issue for more details
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/43335
